# WPF load File error

Tags: c#, wpf, filepath

I have very strange error.

I am loading a .csv file successfully in my WPF ListView, like this

```
var lines = File.ReadAllText(@"Data\File.csv").Split('\n').Where(arg => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg));
```

But, during Debugging and I am getting an error "*Could not find a part of path 'C\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft visual studio 11\Common\IDE\Data\File.csv*"

Why it is looking in the above folder? 
Thank you in advance.

.

Comment: It's looking there because it thinks that's where the current directory is set.  Of a more relevant concern is 'where do you want it to look?'  For example in the root directory of your executable?

Comment: Actually, I want to set relative path to MyAppFolder/Data/File.csv, what I don't understand is why it is throwing the error (in try catch) but, loads correctly the file in ListView.... If the path wasnt correct at all than It wouldn't load?

Comment: You can use Path.Combine to create a fully qualified name.  Or you can dump the environment variables under both conditions and compare them.

Comment: Could you pls elaborate a little bit more, I just want to load this file from Data folder inside ApplicationFolder, during debugging an deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get an error while you are editing, the Designer tries to be smart and display the data for you even design time. That makes sense, the designer is VS IDE component, and it probably has that `C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft visual studio 11\Common\IDE\` as working directory.
You have some choices:

1. Specify full path. But that's not suitable for release.
2. You can determine Design mode.

Comment: I think this is a case , is there an easy way to determine Design mode. Also, I've noticed that this error showing randomly not sure what is causing it